# Displaying Error Page based on the error exception?

Tags: asp.net

I am using the exception catching procedure which is the module to track the errors and it write the error description in a log file in the server.I want to display the error details in a common Error page which is having a multi-line textbox from the common function in the module.Is it possible to do that.If possible,How can I do that....

Try

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

Catch ex as exception

CreateLogFile(Ex)

End Try

The above description is the error catching portion from the code

In the module I have written the CreateLogFile function which write the log file.

I want to display the Error Page after writing the log file which should contain the error details....

Please Help...?.[alt text http://file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Ramesh.DEV/Desktop/bbbb.bmp](http://file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Ramesh.DEV/Desktop/bbbb.bmp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested all of this, but you could try re-throwing the exception.

```
Catch ex as exception
    CreateLogFile(Ex)
    Throw
End Try
```

Then, to handle that, add a new "Global Application Class" to your solution. Visual Studio should then create a new file, Global.asax. In its code behind, do something like:

```
Public Class Global
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication
    Protected Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Server.Transfer("~/Error.aspx")
    End Sub
End Class
```

The benefit of that is it will catch any uncaught exceptions. So then, once in Error.aspx, or whatever:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim ex As Exception = Server.GetLastError()
    If ex Is Nothing Then
        'Can't determine last error
    Else
        ex = ex.GetBaseException()
        
        If ex Is Nothing Then
            'Can't determine last error
        Else
            'Display error message
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

^ For some reason the syntax highlighting javascript is taking those comments as strings.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** If, in any of your previous questions, you received an answer that helped you, maybe consider going back and clicking the green check mark next to that answer. It'll make people more likely to provide answers to your future questions.

Comment: I tried the entire thing and created an error for testing.But couldn't redirect to the Error page. I used the throw statement resulting in this error-'Error executing child request'.

Comment: @Ramesh I'm looking, but there seems to be several different possible causes. When you call `Server.Transfer`, are you sure the page specified in the string exists?

Comment: No,Actually I created the error .... The Error page is opening but in another window.... Why?

Comment: If I put the Throw statement, I am getting the error in the code window which interrupts my execution and forcing me to end the execution.When I end the execution , the Error page is displaying?

Comment: @Ramesh What if you add `<customErrors mode="off"/>` inside the `<system.web>` in Web.config?

Answer (score 0):

After you call your CreateLogFile method, then you would issue a Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer to your error page

Comment: How can I call the Response.Redirect in the module?...
I have written the function inside the module?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect